# In OSGi , getting ClassNotFoundExceptions while trying to use classes from the system exported packages

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am new to OSGi. I am using eclipse PDE 'Kepler Service Release 2'.

I want to make classes inside the javax.servlet package available for my test clients. But I am getting NoClassDefFoundError when , just for testing, trying to create a ServletException object.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException.

I have tried these two ways. both are not working:

**Try 1: using system packages**

I have these startup parameters in my eclipse OSGI Framework:

> -Dorg.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javax.servlet
>          -Dorg.osgi.framework.system.capabilities="osgi.ee; osgi.ee=\"JavaSE
>             \";version:List=\"1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8\""

I can see this Export-Package in the System Bundle (0) : `javax.servlet; version="0.0.0"[exported]`
Im my bundle I have this Import-Package: `org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)",javax.servlet`.

I could not get this working even with a flag `-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*` while starting the container.

**Try 2: using the ExtensionBundle**

My ExtensionBundle has the jar javaee-api-6.0.jar in its classpath and exports the javax.servlet package. 
But still I am getting 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException'.

I dont have any startup parameters for this.

In the Manifest.mf of the extension bundle:
   ...

Bundle-ClassPath: .,javaee-api-6.0.jar
   Export-Package: ....,javax.servlet,...
   Fragment-Host: system.bundle;extension:=framework

...

Am I missing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JRE does not contain the package javax.servlet. So you can not simply export it. You can take a look at the bundle below in maven central. It exports the package. Also remember that the servlet API will not be enough to run a servlet. You will also need an implementation of the osgi HTTPService. Possible implementations are: [felix http service](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html), [org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_equinox.php), [pax-web](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web). So the even better solution might be to install one of these.

`javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0`